# Display lines to function values

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a log plot and after a calculation I get 2-3 x values. I would like to mark the x values and draw a line to the function and draw a line to the y-axis as shown:

[image]

Additionally I would like to add the x-Value to the x-axis where the line is drawn.
How do I do that?

Comment: You will have to draw that line manually as well as the manual x axis label.

Comment: i'm a newbie. Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is:

```
% example data
x = [1e0,  1e1,  1e2, 1e3, 1e4,  1e5 ]; 
y = [1e15, 1e10, 1e6, 1e2, 1e-2, 1e-5];
```

And you have a plot

```
loglog(x,y); 
grid on;
```

You can manually add more plots on top using

```
hold on;
```

Find the limits of your plot axes using `xlim` and `ylim'

```
YBottom = ylim;  YBottom = YBottom(1);
XLeft   = xlim;  XLeft   = XLeft(1);
```

Manually draw the lines you want using the `line` function. E.g. for the 3rd point:

```
line([x(3),  x(3)], [YBottom, y(3)], 'color', 'r', 'linewidth', 5); % vertical
line([XLeft, x(3)], [y(3),    y(3)], 'color', 'r', 'linewidth', 5); % horizontal
```

You can also add annotations anywhere on your plot using the `text` function.
E.g. to add an annotation at a point that prints the coordinates themselves:

```
text(x(3), y(3), sprintf('(%d,%d)', x(3), y(3)));
```